# Search filtering by keywords and column filter in javafx >> MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, search, javafx, filter

First of all I apologize  for my grammar as  english is not my first language, this is my second question for this day and its quite embarrassing already.

I just want to ask as to how I can add a search functionality to my application, like searching for keywords with filtering?

I am able to do minor search functionality like typing words on the search bar and the results will reflect on the table.

What I do want to know though is how to do something like this..

[image]

Say, if I input the word "bronte" and the word "beautiful" and the subject English is selected from the combobox, when i press GO, the result reflected in the tableview should be "of mice and men" and "wuthering heights"

How should i organize my table in the database? as i think the column 'keywords' should not be put this way. I'm out of solutions.

my code as of writing (But really farfetched from what i need):

pupulating tableview using  this sample code:

```
public void loadDatabaseData(){

    String query = "select * from table_sample";

    try {

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            data.add(new table(
                    rs.getString("Name"),
                    rs.getString("Username"),
                    rs.getString("Password"),
                    rs.getString("kiki")
            ));

            table.setItems(data);

        }
        preparedStatement.close();
        rs.close();

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        System.err.println(e);

    }



}
```

Search functionality code:

```
@FXML
public void searchUser()
{
    searchBox.textProperty().addListener((observableValue,oldValue,newValue)->{
        filteredData.setPredicate((Predicate<? super table>)user->{
            if(newValue==null||newValue.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCaseFilter=newValue.toLowerCase();
            if(user.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                return true;
            }
            else if(user.getUsername().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    SortedList<table> sortedData=new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
    table.setItems(sortedData);
}
```

Comment: Since *Of mice and men* doesn't seem to include the *bronte* keyword and there are more rows than *of mice and men* and *wuthering heights* with the *beautiful* keyword I'd say such a query is impossible for any database to get this result unless there is more information involved than we can see in the table...

Comment: a rough representation of what im trying to do:

maybe i can do something like, 

- if it contain the keywords "bronte" OR "beautiful" , then proceed to the next if statement.
- if it is under the subject "English" then display it on the table.

But i don't know where to start and how to organize the columns and tables for this kind of functionality